# Can I use NPAPI plugin to filter HTTP

Tags: http, filtering, npapi

Is it possible to use a NPAPI plugin to filter HTTP traffic in modern browsers (namely firefox and chrome)? I was able to build a simple plugin and register it with FF and Chrome.

Is there any way to use it for low level HTTP filtering? I couldn't find any useful information on the net about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. NPAPI plugins don't affect the browser or browser stack; they affect the handling of a specific mimetype *or* they affect a specific page into which they are inserted as an object tag.

see http://npapi.com/extensions

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I can stop wasting my time now.